# Plotting 2 Independen variables ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I think that this must be something stupid, but I am unable to solve it. 
I have a dataframe in wide format, so in order to use ggplot2, I transformed it in long format and convert into factor the variable called variable.

```
InfidelityM <- melt(Infidelity, id=c("X", "Gender"), measured = c("Partner", "Self"))
InfidelityM$variable <- factor(InfidelityM$variable, labels= c("Partner", "Self"))
```

Then, I try to create the graph

```
bar <- ggplot(InfidelityM, aes(variable, value, fill= "Gender"))
bar + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="bar", position="dodge")
```

However, the graph does not have into account the values of the variable Gender and show me only a couple of colums: one for partner and one for Self.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your syntax on `fill` is incorrect. It should read:

```
bar <- ggplot(InfidelityM, aes(variable, value, fill= Gender))
bar + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="bar", position="dodge")
```

Where `fill=Gender` doesn't have quotes.

Comment: @user2863909 - if Mark solved your question, be sure to check the checkmark next to his answer to indicate that it worked.